# How to display/call the icons dynamically based on the array data in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

***QUESTION: 1 (SOLVED!)***
[image]

How to call/display the icons based on the array data code?

```
data = [{
 img: '01d'
}, {
 img: '02d'
}]

data && data.map((item) => (
      <img src={`./icons/${item['img']}.svg`} />
))
```

What I'm trying to do here is to display the icon based on the `img code` dynamically.

***QUESTION 2***
after adding the `require()`, how to fix the `You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
data && data.map((item) => (
      <img src={`./icons/${data['img']}.svg`} />    // Error: data['img']
))
```

Explainaiton:
data is an array of objects. To access the first element you need to access with either `data[0]['img'].`

But since you have already created a map, you can use the `item` to access the object. So you can now use `item['img']` instead.

```
data && data.map((item) => (
      <img src={`./icons/${item['img']}.svg`} />.      // replace data by item as it contains the object on every iteration
))
```

**UPDATE: As per you 404 error comment,**

The path you provided is not correct. Try this:
Assuming your path is: `ProjectFolder/src/icons/01d.svg`

```
<img alt="" src={getImg(imgName)} />

function getImg(imgName) {
    var fullPath = "icons/" + imgName + ".svg";
    return require(fullPath);
}
```

If it still doesn't work, I suggest you to try with a static img and see if it loads. and try to figure out the path issue
<img alt="" src={require('icons/01d.svg')} />

Comment: @BeginnerCoder Updates provided

Answer (score 0):

when you looping over an array you have a single object in each loop cycle, so you can do this

```
data = [{
 img: '01d'
}, {
 img: '02d'
}]

data && data.map((item) => (
      <img src={`./icons/${item.img}.svg`} />
))
```